# SQL Query: Find highest revenue month/year for a customer

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm looking to query the database to find highest revenue month for all the customers in the system. I have got the query working to pull customers monthly revenue from all the years for which the data is present. But I'm struggling to figure out how to get highest revenue month-year from this data.

The database is SQL Server 2008 R2. 
The columns are: Customer name, Year, Month, and Revenue.
I even tried using Row_Number() and tried partitioning by customer name/year and ordering by revenue. But it didn't work. Maybe I'm making some mistake there.

Here's how I tried to build the base query.

```
Select Customer, Year(orderdatetime) as Year, Month(orderdatetime) as Month, SUM(Revenue)
From Orders
Group By Customer, Year(orderdatetime), Month(orderdatetime)
```

This is how I tried to use Row_Number()

```
WITH Max_Revenue AS
(
Select Customer, Year(orderdatetime) as Year, Month(orderdatetime) as Month, SUM(Revenue), RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION By Year Order By Revenue DESC)
    From Orders
    Group By Customer, Year(orderdatetime), Month(orderdatetime)
)
Select Max_Revenue.Customer, Max_Revenue.Year, Max_Revenue.Month, Max_Revenue.Revenue
From Max_Revenue
Where Max_Revenue.RowNumber = 1
Order By Max_Revenue.Customer asc
```

The data I get back is like:

```
Customer   Month   Year  Revenue
  ABC        2       2012  100
  ABC        3       2013  150
  ABC        5       2012  200
  XYZ        4       2011  500
  XYZ        6       2012  650
  XYZ        7       2012  800
```

What I want as the output is

```
 Customer   Month   Year  Revenue
 ABC        5       2012  200
 XYZ        7       2012  800
```

So every customer's best month and respective year in terms of revenue.

Comment: try using "max" something like select max(revenue) from table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT Customer,
        Year,
        Revenue,
        Month  
 FROM (
       SELECT Customer,
              Year,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION By Customer Order By Revenue DESC) as rank,
              Revenue,
              Month

       FROM (
              Select Customer, 
                     Year(orderdatetime) as Year, 
                     Month(orderdatetime) as Month, 
                     SUM(Revenue) as Revenue
              From   Orders 
              Group By 
                    Customer, 
                    Year(orderdatetime), 
                    Month(orderdatetime)
              ) BS

    GROUP BY Customer,
             Year,
             Month) BS2    
WHERE BS2.rank = 1
```

OR change = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION By Year Order By Revenue DESC to
            = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION By Customer Order By Revenue DESC

Comment: This works perfectly, I missed on adding the last level of nesting query there. Also the only change we need to make here is to add Revenue in the Group By of BS inner SQL otherwise we won't be able to use it in the partition of Row_Number(). That's the only extra thing I added and it's working perfectly now..tx

Comment: Great answer still. Thanks :)